# oracle query to group date difference by hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I am hoping to get some help to write some SQL that I have had no success writing myself.

I have a table with the data:

```
ID    StartDate             EndDate
1     01/01/2000 04:30 AM   01/02/2000 06:15 AM
2     01/03/2000 06:10 AM   01/03/2000 07:00 AM
```

I need to get the following:

```
Hour24     Minutes
04         30
05         60
06         65
07         60
```

In other words, split up date ranges by hour. Then aggregate by hour for each range.
My database is Oracle 11G R2 and I am afraid due to circumstances I cannot use PL/SQL.

I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to write SQL or are you just fishing for answers here? If you have made an attempt, could you please post your SQL statement?

Comment: I think your calculation is wrong for `07`.  That should be `0`.

Comment: And if startdate and enddate are different dates, should all intermediate hours count as 60? Your example says we should ignore the date component completely, but I'm asking since it feels wrong. What if startdate is 01/01/2000 06:15 AM and enddate is 01/02/2000 04:30 AM?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to solve this you just need a list of numbers.

```
with nums as (
      select 0.0 as n from dual
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n < 100
    )
select trunc(t.startdate + n * 1/ 24, 'hh'),
       sum((case when trunc(t.startdate + n * 1/24, 'hh') = trunc(t.startdate, 'hh')
                 then 60 - extract(minute from startdate)
                 else 0
            end) +
           (case when trunc(t.startdate + n * 1/24, 'hh') > trunc(t.startdate, 'hh') and
                      trunc(t.startdate + n * 1/24, 'hh') < trunc(t.enddate, 'hh')
                 then 60
                 else 0
            end) +
           (case when trunc(t.startdate + n * 1/24, 'hh') = trunc(t.enddate, 'hh')
                 then extract(minute from enddate)
                 else 0
            end)
           ) as minutes
from table t join
     nums n
     where trunc(t.startdate + n * 1/24, 'hh') <= t.enddate;
```

This works for up to 100 hours difference in the dates.  You can adjust the `100` for your needs.  You can even use a subquery to get the right maximum value.

There are some tricks that can simplify the logic.  I think the above logic is clearest.  It cycles through the hours.  If the compared hour is the first hour, use 60 - minutes.  If the last, use the minutes.  Otherwise, use 60.

Answer (score 0):

as a first step you need a table with 24 rows. Bad example:

select rownum rnum from all_objects where rownum < 25

then you join that table to your table with the condition that rnum hour is between startdate and enddate

between select and from you would put rnum and a formula to calculate number of minutes in that particular record withing rnum hour

then you would wrap that query in another one with GROUP BY construction.

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime ranges can span more than a day, as your sample data shows, then it is possible they could take up more than 60 minutes of one hour. For example, we have a ridiculous process that takes over 48 hours to complete, so when checking for, lets just say hour 6, the queries based on a 24 hour counter will return 60, when they might actually need to return 120.

```
with hours as (
  select trunc(sysdate, 'hh') - ((rownum - 1) / 24) as testhour
  from dual connect by rownum <= (trunc(sysdate, 'hh') - (trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - (1 / 24))) * 24
)
select
  to_char(h.testhour, 'hh24') as Hour24,
  round(sum((least(t.stopdatetime, h.testhour + (1/24)) - greatest(t.startdatetime, h.testhour)) * 1440)) Minutes
from
  datetimes t,
  hours h
where
  t.stopdatetime >= trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
  and (
    h.testhour between t.startdatetime and t.stopdatetime
    or h.testhour = trunc(t.startdatetime, 'hh')
  )
group by
  to_char(h.testhour, 'hh24')
order by 1
;
```

This query should handle those situations, but it takes much longer to run in it's current form; it will return a datetime for every hour, from the first hour this month to the current hour.